# Send message to user in facebook customer chat plugin as soon as logged in

Tags: facebook, chat, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'm trying to send a message to the user as soon as they click on the chat button on my Customer Chat Plugin, what I want to achieve is exactly the flow from this website: [mobile monkey](https://mobilemonkey.com/)

The flow is:

- User enters page and click `log into messenger`
- chat window opens with message

I can't find any example on how to send the user this message **without the user sending a message first**. To send a message I need the PSID for the user in my php service, but I can't get any response on the user login.

Also, is there any way I can get that PSID on my frontend? What I'm developing requires the bot to ask questions when there is some user action on my website.

edit: Just to be clear, it is **not** the greeting message, it is and actual message when the chat window opens, see ref.

[image]

Comment: If you mean the "Hi, we have answers to questions you might have" message that pops up, this is not part of the Messenger conversation. It is simply a static text that is provided as part of that component of the website.

Comment: Yes, that would probably just be the greeting message, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#steps

Comment: _“Also, is there any way I can get that PSID on my frontend?”_ - no, but you can match PSID to ASID, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching - but that would of course require that the user is logged into your app on your website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer, just had to use a `postback` webhook.

More info here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/webhook-events/messaging_postbacks